# HTML/CSS - Bold underscore character

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am trying to to have a bold underscore character in html and it works in Chrome but not in other browsers (Firefox, Safari, IE) :

```
<b> _ </b>
```

Comment: Er... How can it not work? What does "Not work" mean?

Answer (score 1):

For some font family and font size combinations, a bold “`_`” character may look very similar to, or identical with, a regular “`_`” character. For example, in 10px Arial, the renderings appear to be identical. For Arial Unicode MS, the difference is small or nonexistent even in default font size or larger; this may relate to the fact that Arial Unicode MS has no bold typeface, so browsers apply algorithmic bolding. Such bolding does not affect horizontal strokes much in general, as you can see by bolding characters like “=” or “H”.

There can be differences between browsers due to different font rendering technologies.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;">hellooooo</p>
```